# Slick Slider Show Overflow, Hide Slides

Tags: javascript, slick.js

My slider has 8 slides with infinite looping. Each slide has an image that overflows the slide so I set overflow to visible. All the slides show now but I only want to show 4 slides at a time.

Is it possible to hide all slides except the first 4 slides and then show or hide the next or previous when scrolling? This way there will always be only four slides showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show only the slides with the `slick-active` class and hide the rest.

```
.slick-slide {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide.slick-active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. After 11 slides, at the 12th slide, all the slides disappear for a second and then displays.

Comment: I've been where you are and it's either this or setting the overflow to its initial value.